# How do I resolve xsl:include directives in c++ (can't use .NET framework)

Tags: c++, xslt, msxml6

I need to load an xslt from a database and hold it in memory so that it can be included by another xslt.

I know you can do this using the .NET framework and the xmlPreLoadedResolver class, but unfortunately, we're not allowed to write this as a .NET dll.

Does anyone know if its possible to do this using the msxml6 C++ interfaces?

Comment: Unless you can pass an URI Resolver to the XSLT processor, or the XSLT processor have knowlodge of special protocols, you have to compose the stylesheet yourself. For `xsl:include` is simple as in replacing this instruction for all the content of the `xsl:stylesheet` element.

Comment: Thats pretty much the conclusion I had come to :(

Comment: *bangs head on desk*....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, the only way we could find to get around this was to write some code on loading the top-level xslts which could load up all the dependencies and 'explode' them into the main xslt. These exploded xlsts are then held in memory as required..

Answer (score 0):

MSXML does support XSLT 1.0. See here for more on this: [Creating XSLT Solutions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms766402%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Basically everything is based on the `transformNode` and `transformNodeToObject` methods: [transformNode Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms761399%28VS.85%29.aspx)